Django app sending message to SQS, but worker not executing
I have an AWS SQS set up named celery-celery and I am sending tasks to the SQS queue via Celery when I call an API.
I can see that the messages are getting to the SQS queue (https://sqs.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/718854804674/celery-celery) b/c there is are available messages in the queue, and a new one is added to the queue whenever I call the API.

However, the messages never go away, and they never execute. They just sit in the queue as an available message.
I am running a Django application on Beanstalk.
I am calling the api:
/api/print-hello-world/
Which nvigaes to the url:
path('print-hello-world/', print_hello_world_task, name='print_hello_world')
and then to the view:
def print_hello_world_task(request):
    
    # return JsonResponse({'status': 'API is working'})
    print("Received request to start timer task")
    logger.info("Received request to start timer task")
    task = print_hello_world.delay()  # This triggers the Celery task asynchronously
    print(f"Task started with ID: {task.id}")
    return JsonResponse({'status': 'Task started', 'task_id': task.id})

Which then calls the task in tasks.py:
@shared_task(queue='celery-celery')
def print_hello_world():
    return "Executed"

This is my Procfile:
web: gunicorn --workers 1 rvm.wsgi:application
worker: celery -A rvm worker -l debug --loglevel=DEBUG --queues=celery-celery --logfile=/var/log/celery/celery.log -E

This is my CELERY_ related elements of settings.py:
    AWS_ACCESS_KEY = os.getenv('AWS_ACCESS_KEY')
    AWS_SECRET_KEY = os.getenv('AWS_SECRET_KEY')

    CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND = 'django-db'
    CELERY_CACHE_BACKEND = 'django-cache'
    CELERY_ACCEPT_CONTENT = ['json']
    CELERY_TASK_SERIALIZER = 'json'
    CELERY_TASK_DEFAULT_QUEUE = 'celery-celery'
    CELERY_RESULT_SERIALIZER = 'json'
    CELERY_TIMEZONE = 'UTC'
    CELERY_LOG_FILE = '/var/log/celery/celery.log'

    CELERY_BROKER_URL = 'sqs://{0}:{1}@'.format(AWS_ACCESS_KEY, AWS_SECRET_KEY)

   
    logger.info(f'CELERY_BROKER_URL: {CELERY_BROKER_URL}')


    CELERY_BROKER_TRANSPORT_OPTIONS = {
        'region': 'us-east-1',  # AWS region
        'polling_interval': 1,  # Polling interval for messages
        'visibility_timeout': 3600,  # Visibility timeout for messages
        'broker_connection_retry_on_startup': True,  # Retry connecting on startup
        'use_ssl': True,  # Ensure SSL is used
        'sqs': {
            'signature_version': 'v4',  # Use SigV4 for SQS
        }
    }

This is my celery.py:
import os
from celery import Celery
import warnings
from celery.utils.log import get_logger
from kombu import Queue, Exchange

# Set the default Django settings module for the 'celery' program.
os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'rvm.settings')

app = Celery('rvm')

app.conf.task_default_queue = 'celery-celery'

# Using a string here means the worker doesn't have to serialize
# the configuration object to child processes.
# - namespace='CELERY' means all celery-related configuration keys
#   should have a `CELERY_` prefix.
app.config_from_object('django.conf:settings', namespace='CELERY')


# Load task modules from all registered Django apps.
app.autodiscover_tasks()

app.conf.update(
    broker_connection_retry_on_startup=True,  # As discussed before
)

# This line ensures the worker picks up the tasks from the correct queue
app.conf.task_queues = (
    Queue('celery-celery', Exchange('celery-celery'), routing_key='celery-celery'),
)
# app.control.purge()


# Set up logging
logger = get_logger(__name__)

# Ignore the PendingDeprecationWarning
warnings.filterwarnings('ignore', category=PendingDeprecationWarning)

I know that the messages are getting to SQS b/c this is from the celery.log. See <Name>ApproximateNumberOfMessages</Name><Value>3</Value>:
[2024-08-29 04:19:43,559: DEBUG/MainProcess] Response body:
b'<?xml version="1.0"?><GetQueueAttributesResponse xmlns="http://queue.amazonaws.com/doc/2012-11-05/"><GetQueueAttributesResult><Attribute><Name>ApproximateNumberOfMessages</Name><Value>3</Value></Attribute></GetQueueAttributesResult><ResponseMetadata><RequestId>7c6389e1-ea52-593a-a589-d6a8134d2a9c</RequestId></ResponseMetadata></GetQueueAttributesResponse>'
[2024-08-29 04:19:43,560: DEBUG/MainProcess] Event needs-retry.sqs.GetQueueAttributes: calling handler <botocore.retryhandler.RetryHandler object at 0x7fb8ff92ebd0>
[2024-08-29 04:19:43,560: DEBUG/MainProcess] No retry needed.
[2024-08-29 04:19:43,563: DEBUG/MainProcess] basic.qos: prefetch_count->8

My IAM policy is:

My SQS access policy is here:
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "__owner_statement",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::718854674:root"
      },
      "Action": "SQS:*",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:sqs:us-east-1:718854674:*"
    },
    {
      "Sid": "AllowRvmJenkinsServiceRoleAccess_Part1",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::718854674:role/service-role/rvm-jenkins-service-roll"
      },
      "Action": [
        "sqs:GetQueueAttributes",
        "sqs:SendMessage",
        "sqs:ReceiveMessage",
        "sqs:DeleteMessage"
      ],
      "Resource": "arn:aws:sqs:us-east-1:718854674:celery-celery"
    },
    {
      "Sid": "AllowRvmJenkinsServiceRoleAccess_Part2",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::718854674:role/service-role/rvm-jenkins-service-roll"
      },
      "Action": [
        "sqs:ChangeMessageVisibility",
        "sqs:GetQueueUrl",
        "sqs:ListQueues"
      ],
      "Resource": "arn:aws:sqs:us-east-1:718854674:celery-celery"
    },
    {
      "Sid": "AllowRvmJenkinsUserAccess_Part1",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::718854674:user/rvm-jenkins-user"
      },
      "Action": [
        "sqs:GetQueueAttributes",
        "sqs:SendMessage",
        "sqs:ReceiveMessage",
        "sqs:DeleteMessage"
      ],
      "Resource": "arn:aws:sqs:us-east-1:718854674:celery-celery"
    },
    {
      "Sid": "AllowRvmJenkinsUserAccess_Part2",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::718854674:user/rvm-jenkins-user"
      },
      "Action": [
        "sqs:ChangeMessageVisibility",
        "sqs:GetQueueUrl",
        "sqs:ListQueues"
      ],
      "Resource": "arn:aws:sqs:us-east-1:718854674:celery-celery"
    }
  ]
}

The the questions is: why are my celery tasks not being executed by the worker?
I have tried nearly everything and I can't figure out why the worker tasks are not executing.
Thanks for the help!

Ok so my config may have been right, but I decided to go w/ redis cache instead.
The major problem i ran into w/ that was I need to create a custom cache that has encryption OFF and Cluster mode Disabled.
You cannot set these settings in the UI at this time, so I ran this command on my beanstalk EC2:
aws elasticache create-replication-group     --replication-group-id prod-redis-group1     --replication-group-description "Production Redis cluster mode disabled group without encryption"     --engine redis     --cache-node-type cache.m5.large     --num-node-groups 1     --replicas-per-node-group 1     --automatic-failover-enabled     --cache-subnet-group-name my-prod-subnet-group     --security-group-ids sg-0a228f8f1343d23ae     --preferred-maintenance-window sun:05:00-sun:09:00     --tags Key=Name,Value=prod-redis-group1

That worked great.
After that I had to add a file to set the .env vars b/c for some reason they aren't passed form the beanstalk config... I'll try and work on understanding that later. But basically i have:
sudo vi /etc/celery_worker.env which contains DB stuff:
DB_NAME=blah
DB_HOST=blahblahblah.rds.amazonaws.com
DB_USERNAME=blah
DB_PASSWORD=blah
DEBUG=False
ENVIRONMENT=PRODUCTION

I'm going to keep posting notes here. I will re-organize and finalize this answer once complete.
